# How can I communicate with an object on a remote machine?

Tags: java, networking

I know my IP address, and that of my friend.
How can I transfer objects/files between the two machines?
I am an advanced Java programmer, but have never worked with networks before.

EDIT:
I am now using an API called jnmp2p ( http://code.google.com/p/jnmp2p/ ).
It works fine when I use internal IPs, but fails when I give the external ones.

How do I connect to a computer that isn't on my private network?

Comment: is "friend" human or software?

Comment: You can use scp :) The description of your problem is not to detailed! You want to implement some application in Java? You want to use some already made solution? You want to use Java or other language?

Answer (score 4):

If you looking for communication between two java applications and *do not want to meddle with the low level networking details*, then you can use following two approaches, depending on the type of applications you are dealing with.

- If both the application (on two machines) are java standalone applications, then **RMI** is the best bet. Check out the basics from these links ([1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html),[2](http://www.onezerozeroone.eu/html/rmi_howto.html))
- If your application (receiving files/objects) is a web application then its you can write the Servlet on the serve side and then write a client application to send files/objects(binary) to server. [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) is very popular library for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Anyways, I am using an API called jnmp2p. I have found it to be pretty intuitive and easy to use, although it uses some reflection techniques. 
( http://code.google.com/p/jnmp2p/ )

Answer (score 0):

Author of jnmp2p here. I don't maintain the library any more because I've moved onto other things. However I had some comments.

Peer to peer communication with IPs outside your private network is a hard problem. This is because stateful NATs and firewalls on both ends have become common-place, which prevent you from establishing connections between machines directly.

For example skype uses a rendezvous service where both machines start outbound connections to a third machine and communicate via that. Aside from setting up additional infrastructure that any peer to peer solution is going to be limited to subnets within your NAT, so solutions like JNMP2P or RMI (with gross modifications) are going to be your best bet.